# NoClassDefFoundError happens at the probability of 0.3%

Tags: android

We have an app which has large amount of users and is keeping tract of the crush ration at one monitoring platform. Recently the ratio of NoClassDefError happens much more than before(about 0.3% for this crush) .

The stack prints below:

```
1Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.company.framework.net.NetworkWorker
2    at adz.run(UserCenterDataLoad.java:70)
3    at com.company.framework.app.Application.d(Application.java:45)
4    at atv.run(Unknown Source)
5    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.AsyncExecutor$1.run(AsyncExecutor.java:116)
6    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
7    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
8    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
main thread
formatted
1    at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.HwWidgetFactoryImpl.newHwDialogStub(HwWidgetFactoryImpl.java:350)
2    at android.hwcontrol.HwWidgetFactory.getHwDialogStub(HwWidgetFactory.java:209)
3    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:205)
4    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:179)
5    at sp.<init>(BaseFullScreenDialog.java:30)
6    at sp.<init>(BaseFullScreenDialog.java:26)
7    at sr.<init>(HomeDialog.java:17)
8    at com.company.home.components.dialogs.HomeUpdateDialog.<init>(HomeUpdateDialog.java:58)
9    at com.company.bll.MainActivity.startHomeDialogAfterSplash(MainActivity.java:987)
10    at com.company.bll.MainActivity.d(MainActivity.java:439)
11    at com.company.bll.MainActivity.b(MainActivity.java:367)
12    at com.company.bll.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:266)
13    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6372)
14    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
15    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2432)
16    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2539)
17    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168)
18    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
19    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
20    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
21    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5665)
22    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
23    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
24    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
```

The class NetworkWorker is used every where as an entrance of network operation and this crush never happens in our test team. And what is more, if this class is missing, the user may crush every where.

The interesting thing is that this crush only happens at android 5.0 or later
[image]

anyone has any experience of that? this crush is hard to fix not only for we cannot reproduce it but also whenever we change  something to test it, we have to release it and wait before enough person use it.

Comment: it seems that this class `NetworkWorker` is accessible in compile time but not during runtime. Ensure that this class is accessible by the application in runtime

Comment: @nandsito I am sure it is accessible during runtime. For we can run it very well in our hand and by test guys. The crush only happens for few users in few time

Comment: your log tells otherwise... what is the difference between the test app and the production app?

Comment: they are the same one.